# App asks for USB permission on every Phone restart

Tags: android, permissions, usb, restart

I'm using an USB-Receiver to handle the Communication with a Temperature Sensor attached via USB to the Phone.

Everything is working fine so far, but if i restart the Phone, the App throws an **USB-Permission pop-up directly after restarting**, even if there isn't any USB-Device attached to the Phone at that Moment.

Has anyone an Idea of what's causing this strange Problem?

**[ EDIT:** I'm Sorry, the App isn't asking for USB Permission, the popup asks if i want to Open the app if "this device is connected" but there's obviously no device attached.**]**

Here is the Code of the USB-Receiver:

```
//Initial USB Settings Receiver
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                final UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                // is usb permission has been granted, try to open a connection
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        // call method to set up device communication
                        Constants result = mcp2221.open();

                        if (result != Constants.SUCCESS) {
                            //nothing by now
                        } else {
                            openConnectionToMCP2221();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            // close the connection and release all resources
            closeAllResources();
            // leave a bit of time for the COM thread to close
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            mcp2221Comm = null;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device detached",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            final UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (device != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device attached",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mStopUSBThread=false;

                // only try to connect if an MCP2221 is attached
                if (device.getVendorId() == MCP2221_VID && device.getProductId() == MCP2221_PID) {
                    Constants result = mcp2221.open();

                    switch (result) {
                        case SUCCESS:
                            openConnectionToMCP2221();
                            break;
                        case CONNECTION_FAILED:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case NO_USB_PERMISSION:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: no USB permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mcp2221.requestUsbPermission(mPermissionIntent);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
};
```

And here is the onCreate() part:

```
//USB Connection
    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);

    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    //Checking if theres a Device already connected
    .......
```

Comment: Some code from your app maybe? Do you have any `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver?

Comment: I'll add some code.

No i only check for a connected device once on App-start, just in case the Sensor is already Connected, and then the USB Receiver listens for ATTACHED and DETACHED devices and asks for permission once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! 
It was an

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

that was declared in AndroidManifest.xml under `<activity>`.

I don't fully understand, why it caused this Bug, but removing it kept the functionality of my App while getting rid of the Problem.

Only 'negative' aspect might be, that now the App doesn't ask to open if the Sensor is attached to the phone.